# Joomla 2.5 and Jomsocial Integration. Users can't save data

Tags: css, joomla2.5, jomsocial

I've spent the last week researching this bug, tried many things and I'm now thinking it might just be something simple I'm overlooking.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Installed Rocket Theme rocket Launcher, template=Radiance for Joomla 2.5
Installed JomSocial full version for Joomla 2.5
Installed every app and every mod that came zipped with the JomSocial component.
Followed all install directions successfully.

Problem:  About Half of the users cannot save profile changes on the front end.  When they visit any of the links made available by JomSocial to edit their profile, upon clicking the "Save" button, the error message in a pop up box comes up, "Your 'Password' and 'Verify Password' does not match."

I've compared the users that have this error to the users that don't get this message and there are no correlations whatsoever.  Sign up date does not matter, modules don't matter, third party modules or plug ins do not matter.

I've checked settings both globally within JomSocial and specific settings, such as "Custom Profiles" and all of their fields.

I have literally gone through every single setting within the JomSocial Configurations.
I've tested each one, I've cleared the cache, logged in on the front end with a test user and tried to save the profile and the same message keeps coming up.

As a last resort, I uninstalled JomSocial and all of its plugins and mods.
After Reinstalling JomSocial, same error comes up.

I am at a stalemate and cannot understand what I am doing wrong!

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what the issue is. Although your members fill out the account information page they must click the account details tab that has their password, and on that page they must enter their password in order to save their stats. It's really annoying but its the only way to make profile changes. Took me a bit to figure that out. The password verification should be on the same tab as the changes that are being made.  Jomsocial needs to correct this. Or you can Alert-password verification in your code when the save button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion you could check.

It's important that users are always at either **your-domain.com/...** or **www.your-domain.com/...**

If your site is configured in such a way that they can go from one to the other then there will be problems. Technically they are considered different domains and the cookie set when you login at one won't be good at the other.

If you are able to reproduce the problem yourself, try logging in at your-domain.com and watch the URL in your browser as you go from page to page and do stuff. Logout and repeat from www.your-domain.com

If we are lucky this will pinpoint the problem.

The easiest solution in this case, is to redirect all site traffic to www.your-domain.com (or the opposite) via .htaccess. I use the following in .htaccess, you will find lot's of [variations online](http://bit.ly/15HfKYG)

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^your-domain\.com$  
RewriteCond %{http_host}   !^$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.your-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Even if this doesn't solve your immediate problem, for SEO reasons it's good to redirect everyone to the one domain anyway.

Good luck, hope this might help!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and it was very annoying until I figured out what was happening and how to prevent it.  Your browser is storing your password and automatically entering it into the password field.  Jomsocial is not requiring the password to change your settings- you can test this by just deleting the pre-filled password and saving your profile changes.  To fix, remove the saved password for your user (In Firefox, it is in Tools-Options-Security-Saved Passwords).  In the future, when your browser asks to remember your password, do not allow, or as a more permanent solution, select the option to never remember a password for this site.